# bash arithmetic expansion seems to be prone to injection attacks

Tags: bash, arithmetic

Suppose you want your script to take variables from environment:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eu

if (( ${A-} )); then
    echo true
else
    echo false
fi
```

Arithmetic expansion seems to be more reasonable here to handle `(empty)`, `0`, `1` cases, or else:

```
if [ "${A-}" ] && [ "${A-}" != 0 ]; then
```

But then,

```
$ A='1 - 1' ./1.sh
false
$ A='B = 1' ./1.sh
true
```

So now you can basically change variables, which you generally don't want to allow. What would you suggest? How to process boolean flags taken from environment variables?

Comment: How was this an injection attack? Did you perhaps mean `A='A = 1 - 1' ./sh`?  It doesn't work with the version that uses `[ ]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're unsure if variable holds an int, you can validate its value:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eu

vint() {
    local v
    for v; do
        if echo "$v" | egrep '[^0-9]' &> /dev/null; then
            printf '%s: %s: not an int\n' "$0" "$v" >&2
            exit 1
        fi
    done
}

vint "${A-}"
if (( ${A-} )); then
    echo true
else
    echo false
fi
```

This is as far as I could take it.